# Database Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, relational-database

I have a question regarding stored procedure. Suppose I have 2 tables `User` and `Education` in my database.

```
Table User       Table Education  
UserID           University
UserName         Qualification
...              Field of Study
...              .........
....             .........
....             UserID
```

The question is, for example: there is two degrees (education) for one user, when I tried to update on of the degree, it will update both of the degree.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[UpdateEducation]
   @University,
   @Qualification,
   @FieldOfStudy,
   @Grade,
   @GDate,
   @Location,
   @Major,
   @AddtionalInfo,
   @UserID
AS
BEGIN

Update Education SET

University =@University,
Qualification=@Qualification,
FieldOfStudy=@FieldOfStudy,
Grade=@Grade,
GDate=@GDate,
Location=@Location,
Major=@Major,
AddtionalInfo=@AddtionalInfo

WHERE UserID=@UserID

END

GO
```

Hope someone can help me as I'm still new to this. Tq

Comment: Does your Education table have a primary key? If so, what is it? If not, how can you uniquely identify an education record for a user?

Comment: Hi,you mean like Education ID ?

Comment: Sorry mate @JohnGibb, will be more careful with the tittle in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure cannot technically update the row without all the information required to uniquely identify the record that it is updating.

You can solve this a couple ways:

1. Introduce a separate primary key on the Education table for lookup
   purposes.
2. Pass the original data (before the update) into your Stored
   Procedure so that you can lookup the exact row that you are trying
   to change.
3. Identify a separate composite unique key that can be used for lookup
   that does not include data that will be modified.
4. Use some updatable cursor (may not be possible depending on what the
   client technology is).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you have there is your user table will be a 1 to many on the education table.  Your update is telling it to update all records in education table where the UserID = @UserId.  Your update statement needs to reference a specific row in the education table, along these lines.

```
Update Education
   set field = value
where UserId = UserIdValue
and {pickAnotherField} = newFieldValue
```

However you still run the risk of multiple and unintentional updates this way, the better solution would be to add an unique identifier (Education_ID) and make it a primary key.  Then you can use it in your update and be certain of only ever updating a single row.